# Draggable flexbox slider using javascript works but shakes

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox slider I'm working on but don't have the js running smoothly. The dragging function works close to how I want it, but the content jumps around/ shakes when dragging. Not sure if the problem is with the js or because of a conflict with the CSS. Or maybe I should be using different event listeners?

The very last chunk of js is the dragging function. Thanks

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let sliderWrapper = document.querySelector('.slider-wrapper');

let pressed = false;
let startx;
let x;

container.addEventListener('mousedown', (e)=>{
  pressed = true;
  startx = e.offsetX - sliderWrapper.offsetLeft;
  container.style.cursor = 'grabbing'
});

container.addEventListener('mouseenter', ()=>{
  container.style.cursor = 'grab'
});

container.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=>{
  container.style.cursor = 'grab'
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup',()=>{
  pressed = false;
});

container.addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=>{
  if(!pressed) return;
  e.preventDefault();

  x = e.offsetX

  sliderWrapper.style.left = `${x - startx}px`;
});
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  width: 90vw;
  left: 05vw;
  top: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: inherit;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

.slider-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.element{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="element" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/f19.png/mmm">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="element" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/f71.png/mmm">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="element" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png/mmm">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not saying I like your code, or is going to magically work like your dream, but changing `x = e.offsetX` to `x = e.clientX` worked for me.

Comment: thanks, that did fix it. Do you have any idea why my function wouldn't work with offset?

Comment: `e.offsetX` was giving integer values instead of doubles, which in my opinion shouldn't do that, but it's an experimental technology.... so I wouldn't use it anyways.